# Can I mix 2*2 memory sticks with 2*4 in a Imac 27 i5

Tags: imac, memory-limit

I have an iMac 27" with 2x 2GB memory sticks. Can I add 2x 4GB memory sticks?

Does it matter how they are installed in the system?

Comment: 2x 2 **GB** memory sticks?

Answer (score 1):

[Apple support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1423#1)

> Maximum memory    16 GB
>
> Note: For the iMac (Late 2009) models, you can use 2 GB or 4 GB RAM
>   SO-DIMMs of 1066 MHz DDR3 SDRAM in each slot. For the iMac (Mid 2010)
>   and iMac (Mid 2011) models, use 2 GB or 4 GB RAM SO-DIMMs of 1333 MHz
>   DDR3 SDRAM in each slot.

As for installation:

> i5 and i7 Quad Core iMac computers come with both top memory slots
>   populated. These computers will not start up if only a single DIMM is
>   installed in any bottom slot; these computers should operate normally
>   with a single DIMM installed in any top slot. Core Duo iMac computers
>   should operate normally with a single DIMM installed in any slot, top
>   or bottom. ("Top" and "bottom" slots refer to the orientation of the
>   slots in the pictures below. "Top" refers to the slots closest to the
>   display; "bottom" refers to the slots closest to the stand).

There is more relevant information in the top link.